# Query SQL DBs for their Version of origin

Tags: sql-server

After restoring several SQL DBs to my instance of SQL Server, is there any way to query the DBs to determine what version they came from before I restored them?

The query "select @@Version" appears to query my instance rather than the individual DB, but I'd like to know which DBs came from Express, the past version, etc.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Express, Standard, etc are SQL Server editions, not databases versions. You seem to want the [compatibility_level](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Picture6_thumb.png) that it originated from and would likely be at still...

```
select 
  name, 
  compatibility_level
from sys.databases
```

Answer (score 1):

Even before restoring the database you can find the version you are about to restore. Run the below statement with your backup path..

> RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'F:\backups\backupName.bak'

The **DatabaseVersion** column will give you the Which server version was used to create that backup file. (do a lookup for the version #)

The **CompatibilityLevel** column will give you the Database compatibility level it was under when operating.